# How to get Model ID of the Latest Version registered in Azure Machine Learning Service Model Registry using az ml cli?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

Using Azure Machine Learning CLI extension, how do we get the Model ID for the latest version of a Model (with known model name)?

To get the entire list of Model Details with a given name the command is

```
az ml model list --model-name [Model_Name] --resource-group [RGP_NAME] --subscription-id [SUB_ID] --workspace-name [WS_NAME]
```

Running this will give a list of all the models:

```
[
  {
    "createdTime": "2021-03-19T07:02:03.814172+00:00",
    "framework": "Custom",
    "frameworkVersion": null,
    "id": "model:2"
    "name": "model",
    "version": 3
  },
  {
    "createdTime": "2021-03-19T06:46:34.301054+00:00",
    "framework": "Custom",
    "frameworkVersion": null,
    "id": "model:2",
    "name": "model",
    "version": 2
  },
  {
    "createdTime": "2021-03-19T06:38:56.558385+00:00",
    "framework": "Custom",
    "frameworkVersion": null,
    "id": "model:1",
    "name": "model",
    "version": 1
  }
]
```

The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/model?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_cli_ml_az_ml_model_list) mentions, we can use a `-l` parameter to get the latest version details:

```
az ml model list --model-name [Model_Name] --resource-group [RGP_NAME] --subscription-id [SUB_ID] --workspace-name [WS_NAME] -l
```

However, running this gives the following error:

```
ERROR: UnrecognizedArgumentError: unrecognized arguments: -l
```

What is the syntax to use this `-l` flag?

Comment: This reference is part of the azure-cli-ml extension for Azure CLI and requires version 2.0.28 or higher.  What's the version of your Azure CLI?

Comment: What is the command to get the version number. I tried `az ml -v` but it is not the right one.

Comment: try to use `az -v`.

Comment: azure-cli 2.18.0, azure-cli-ml 1.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we wish to obtain the model-id for the latest model, instead of using `az ml model` list with `-l` flag, using `az model show` will return the details for the latest model. The syntax to get a string for model-id will be:

```
az ml model show --model-id $(TRN_MODEL_ID) --resource-group $(AML_TRN_RG) --subscription-id $(AML_TRN_SUB_ID) --workspace-name $(AML_TRN_WS) --query name -o tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent a fun few hours wrestling with this. Running something like

```sh
az ml model list -w your_workspace_name -g your_resource_group_name -l -n name_of_your_registered_model
```

will get you back some JSON that looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "createdTime": "2022-03-04T16:05:47.103407+00:00",
    "framework": "Custom",
    "frameworkVersion": null,
    "id": "name_of_your_registered_model:3",
    "name": "name_of_your_registered_model",
    "version": 3
  }
]
```

This is well and good for a human, but not much use to a machine. The azure cli supports something called [JMESPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli), which allows you to write a query against the result of a CLI command. Running

```sh
az ml model list -w your_workspace_name -g your_resource_group_name -l -n name_of_your_registered_model --query "[0].{id:id}" -o tsv
```

should get you back

```
"name_of_your_registered_model:3"
```

Which you can then use in an env var or whatever other use case you have.