# Getting error while downloading the model in Azure Pipeline using azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I have created a CI-CD pipeline for my machine learning model. After my model training is completed , I have registered the model. I am trying to download the model using Azure Cli with the below inline command :

```
az ml model download -g $(azureml.resourceGroup) -w $(azureml.workspaceName) -i $(jq -r .modelld metadata/model.json) -t ./models --overwrite
```

But I am getting error as below :

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.15/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_cli/cli_command.py:11: FutureWarning: azureml.core: AzureML support for Python 3.6 is deprecated and will be dropped in an upcoming release. At that point, existing Python 3.6 workflows that use AzureML will continue to work without modification, but Python 3.6 users will no longer get access to the latest AzureML features and bugfixes. We recommend that you upgrade to Python 3.7 or newer. To disable SDK V1 deprecation warning set the environment variable AZUREML_DEPRECATE_WARNING to 'False'
  from azureml.core import get_run
ERROR: argument --model-id/-i: expected one argument
```

As I am very much new to Azure Devops I could not able to identify the issue here. How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is this returning $(jq -r .modelld metadata/model.json) ideally model Id should be a number 1,3 etc.. refer the ms document here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml(v1)/model?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ml(v1)-model-download and refer this SO thread answer to list the model id- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704314/how-to-get-model-id-of-the-latest-version-registered-in-azure-machine-learning-s/71648195#71648195 and use that model Id in your command and check?

Comment: Regarding this warning = FutureWarning: azureml.core: AzureML support for Python 3.6 is deprecated and will be dropped in an upcoming release. At that point, existing Python 3.6 workflows that use AzureML will continue to work without modification, but Python 3.6 users will no longer get access to the latest AzureML features and bugfixes. We recommend that you upgrade to Python 3.7 or newer. To disable SDK V1 deprecation warning set the environment variable AZUREML_DEPRECATE_WARNING to 'False' >  upgrade your python version to 3.7 also azure ml v1 SDK and CLI is getting deprecated

Comment: Refer Important note here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/reference-azure-machine-learning-cli?view=azureml-api-1 and refer here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/introduction?view=azureml-api-1 to upgrade refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-migrate-from-v1?view=azureml-api-1

Comment: @SiddheshDesai - I have updated my error message. How can I give the model id number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below code to download the az ml model with model ID, ***You can find the model id which is the name & version of your modelname:versionumber modelml:1 by visiting your Azure ML workspace Model like below:-***

[image]

***My Azure Devops CLI Task:-***

**YAML Script:-**

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2

inputs:

azureSubscription: '<subscription>'

scriptType: 'bash'

scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'

inlineScript: |

az extension add -n azure-cli-ml

az ml model download --model-id modelml:1 --target-dir <path-where-you-want-to-download-the-model> --resource-group siliconrg12 --workspace-name siliconmlws
```

> I have referred this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml%28v1%29/model?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ml%28v1%29-model-download) for az ml model download command.

**Output:-**

[image]

**My Azure CLI code locally:-**

```bash
az ml model download --model-id modelml:1 --target-dir C:\ML --resource-group siliconrg12 --workspace-name siliconmlws
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the spelling of your command> az ml model download -g $(azureml.resourceGroup) -w $(azureml.workspaceName) -i $(jq -r **.modelld** >> modelId << metadata/model.json) -t ./models --overwrite.

its MODELID, but not MODELLD